# jQuery trigger click on element with "onclick" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input element with `onclick` attribute attached to it:

```
<input id="" type="radio" name="" value="" onclick="SetUniqueRadioButton('rptrDelRates.*grpDelRate', this);">
```

Everything is working good, but when I decide to trigger click manually on this element using `jQuery` I get the error below:

> Invalid regular expression: /rptrDelRates.*grpDelRate/: Stack overflow

**jQuery call:**

```
$('.setup-radio').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('input').trigger('click');      
    return false;
});
```

Comment: you dont' have class `.setup-radio` in your input.

Comment: @SumanBogati No, the input is inside an element with the class `setup-radio`.

Comment: We'll need to see the `SetUniqueRadioButton` function's code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can call the native doms onclick directly:

```
 $(".setup-radio")[0].onclick();
```

without jquery:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("test_default")[0].onclick();
```

Comment: That's absolutely amazing answer! Learned something new today and solved the problem. I will mark as accepted answer when I can.

Comment: @Morpheus: Glad it helps. It will even work if you remove return false from click handler.

Answer (score 0):

your **SetUniqueRadioButton** function must add **event.stopPropagation();**

code may case loop because of bubble